# Run multiple main classes in one sbt run

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

When I do sbt run for multiple classes with main I get an option which main class to run such as:

```
 [1] SparkJob1
 [2] SparkJob2
 [3] SparkJob3
 [4] SparkJob4
 [5] SparkJob5
```

When I select one it works fine, but I would like to run all the classes together in parallel.
Is there a way to so, please help me if I could do this by anyway
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that opening multiple terminals and run the main code. And running code in IntelliJ ide it will automatically open the new terminal in ide.

Comment: Is it not possible to run in one terminal i.e. just by 1 sbt run command

Comment: Nopes, this is impossible. Even if possible think how will you be able to distinguish everything in one screen of multiple classes status.

Comment: Ya ok, I thought it was not possible but was not sure thanks for confirming.